# Using unknown/undefined keyboard (keymap) in hammerspoon

Tags: hammerspoon, karabiner

I have attached to my mac a keyboard with additional (nonstandard) keys. See the image at the end of post.

Here is my testing Hammerspoon `init.lua`

```lua
local hyper = {"cmd", "alt", "ctrl", "shift"}
hs.hotkey.bind(hyper, "E", function()
    hs.alert.show("Hyper E")
end)

hs.hotkey.bind(nil, "help", function()
    hs.alert.show("HELP")   -- works
end)

-- hs.hotkey.bind(nil, "copy", function()
--  hs.alert.show("COPY")   -- error
-- end)
```

If uncommenting the above block, the reload showing error:

```
2022-11-28 11:28:06: *** ERROR: ...merspoon.app/Contents/Resources/extensions/hs/hotkey.lua:415: Invalid key: copy - this may mean that the key requested does not exist in your keymap (particularly if you switch keyboard layouts frequently)
```

The Macos silently ignoring the nonstandard keys. (probably because no valid keymap definition file exists).

**However**, the `Karabiner-Elements` correctly find all keys. This is a copy from the event-watcher.

```json
[
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"help"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "117 (0x0075)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"help"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "117 (0x0075)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"stop"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "120 (0x0078)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"stop"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "120 (0x0078)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"again"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "121 (0x0079)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"again"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "121 (0x0079)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"menu"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "118 (0x0076)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"menu"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "118 (0x0076)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"undo"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "122 (0x007a)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"undo"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "122 (0x007a)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"select"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "119 (0x0077)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"select"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "119 (0x0077)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"copy"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "124 (0x007c)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"copy"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "124 (0x007c)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"execute"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "116 (0x0074)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"execute"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "116 (0x0074)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"paste"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "125 (0x007d)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"paste"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "125 (0x007d)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"find"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "126 (0x007e)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"find"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "126 (0x007e)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"key_code":"cut"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "123 (0x007b)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"key_code":"cut"},
    "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)",
    "usage": "123 (0x007b)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "down",
    "name": {"pointing_button":"button1"},
    "usagePage": "9 (0x0009)",
    "usage": "1 (0x0001)",
    "misc": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "up",
    "name": {"pointing_button":"button1"},
    "usagePage": "9 (0x0009)",
    "usage": "1 (0x0001)",
    "misc": ""
  }
]
```

**The question: could use this keyboard in `hammerspoon` - e.g. bind let say the <kbd>copy</kbd> key. without creating macos's keymap file, only using `Karabiner`?**

Because one image = 1000 words, here is the pic of my kbd.

[image]

Comment: you can try this debug print for hammerspoon: https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2937#issuecomment-929830848 - but the code also assume that the key is in the keymap - but maybe you get a hint when you print the `event:getKeyCode()`

Comment: even if you can not find an mapping - you can use the event watcher `hs.eventtap.new` to do actions when you see a keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hammerspoon only recognizes, and thus supports, a specific list of keys. You can find that list in the [Hammerspoon docs](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.keycodes.html#map). I don't see `copy` in that list so it is no surprise it doesn't work. I'd suggest filing a GitHub issue requesting its addition, and in the meantime, using Karabiner as a workaround.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).